# Sharing data within my iCloud Drive anonymously with other devices in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, share, icloud, uiactivityviewcontroller

Swift 4, iOS 11.x
I read here that I can share files on my iCloud dive in this article http://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/02/07/how-to-share-icloud-drive-files/ but I don't see the same options in my code.

I want to able to share image files with individuals using my app, such that teacher stores images on his iCloud account, and student can read said images.

My implementation looks like this, which lets me share files, but I don't see the same menus as I do in the files app. In particular I don't see the show people option.

[image]

I am using the UIActivityController method?

```
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [file2ShareURL], applicationActivities: nil)
 activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
 self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Am I chasing a rainbow?